# Apply VCL style to WinAPI dialog created in other thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi, vcl-styles

We have a Delphi application which shows dialogs using WinAPI in separate (not UI) thread. It works fine. Now we want to apply VCL styles to this application. But style correctly applies only to forms in UI thread, not for dialog in other thread. Even if I call TStyleManager.SetStyle before showing dialog in other thread. If I call TStyleManager.SetStyle and DialogBoxParamW in UI thread, style is successfully applied. Is there any workaroud to enforce a VCL style to dialog created in other thread?

[image]

Simple example:

```
procedure ApplyStyle;
begin
  TStyleManager.SetStyle('Obsidian');
end;

function DialogProc(Dialog: HWnd; Msg: DWord; WParam: DWord;
  LParam: integer): LongBool; stdcall;
begin
end;

procedure ShowDialog;
begin
  DialogBoxParamW(hInstance, PChar('CUSTOM_DIALOG'), 0, @DialogProc, 0);
  if GetLastError <> 0 then
    ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
end;

type
  TDialogThread = class(TThread)
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

procedure TDialogThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  ApplyStyle;
  ShowDialog;
end;

// same thread
procedure TForm4.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ApplyStyle;
  ShowDialog;
end;

// other thread
procedure TForm4.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  t: TDialogThread;
begin
  t := TDialogThread.Create(True);
  t.FreeOnTerminate := false;
  t.Start;
end;
```

Comment: VCL styles are for VCL forms and controls. This dialog is not VCL.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But why style is successfully applied (please see the screenshot), if I call TStyleManager.SetStyle and DialogBoxParamW in main thread?

Comment: OK, fair point. Don't know. By the way, the error checking is wrong. You need to test the return value to determine if the calk to DialogBoxParam failed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the VCL hooks Win32 dialogs to apply VCL styles to them as well, for a consistent experience.

Comment: Is the issue that VCL styles depends upon code in the VCL message loop?

Comment: I think what does most of the magic for styling non VCL controls is via a `WH_CBT` hook:   `FSysHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, @HookCBProc, 0, GetCurrentThreadId);`. This is done when the style engine is initialized, upon unit initialization. Note the thread ID, which should be just the main thread then.

Comment: @nil It turns out than `TCustomStyleEngine` (which contains `FSysHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, @HookCBProc, 0, GetCurrentThreadId);`) does not support multithreading. Maybe it possible to write my own code where I call `SetWindowsHookEx` with other thread ID and my own `HookCBProc` and in `HookCBProc` create some sys hooks (`TSysDialogStyleHook`, etc.) for stylization of dialogs in this thread. Will this lead to conflicts with stylization in the main thread?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would be possible - or even worthwile: how much of the styling code would you have to reproduce multi-threaded to make it work? Would it be an option for you to show the dialogs in the main threads context with `Synchronize`?